# Key name passed through javascript is changed while requesting in the handler page

Tags: c#, javascript, handler

```
$.getJSON("/mypath/myHandler.ashx", { method: "myAction", selectedIds: selectedIds, reportid: reportId },
function (data) { });
```

This is where i am passing the data to the handler.
And in my handler page, 
when i try to retrieve the selectedIds value by trying the below code i get null.

```
context.Request["selectedIds"];
```

After investigating the AllKeys in the context, i came to know that the key name is changed to **selectedIds[]**

Now, i tried with below code and it gives me the values passed correctly.

```
context.Request["selectedIds[]"];
```

Why is the name changed ? Is this because i am retrieving it in a wrong way ?

And i think adding **[]** to the name while retrieving it doesn't seem to be a good idea. It just feels like temporary solution. Please suggest the best.

Comment: Is this array in your javascript ? I meant "selectedIds"

Comment: It's because of that. If you want to send only one id, then send specific data, if not find how to send and get array using handler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809791/send-json-array-to-ashx-handler